# Writting special characters to console in C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, utf-8, special-characters

I have written a program in C++ to query music-related meta-data. However, when writing results to console I realized that some of the artists have special characters in their name, UTF-8 to be specific. So far I have learned to display special characters by their character codes like so:

```
cout << "\u0394" << "\n";
```

The code above should display "Δ" according to http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ but instead it displays "Œî" and I believe this has to do with the encoding of the console.

I did some research on the issue and came across a sample program that should straiten out my issue by instead I get the following errors that I cannot seem to get around.

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    _setmode (_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    wcout << L"AaĄąﬂ" << endl;

    return 0;
}

../main.cpp:1:16: warning: io.h: No such file or directory
../main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../main.cpp:7: error: '_fileno' was not declared in this scope
../main.cpp:7: error: '_O_U8TEXT' was not declared in this scope
../main.cpp:7: error: '_setmode' was not declared in this scope
../main.cpp:8: error: 'wcout' was not declared in this scope
../main.cpp:8: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I am aware that there is loads of information on this out there but I have done enough research, in my opinion, to warrant posting here. One of the reasons that I believe I cannot solve this issue is because none of the information I have read on this topic works for MacOSX. I am also using Eclipse Kepler.

Any information on how to get my sample program to work or display to the console correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding of the Eclipse console to utf-8? See [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/) guide.

Comment: "Special characters, UTF-8 to be specific" may sound like words, but doesn't actually make sense. Make sure you [understand the basics](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) of the subject at hand.

Comment: Thanks @sbugert that was the fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sbugert...

How to change the encoding of the console in Eclipse Kepler:
Run > Run Configurations 
Navigate to your current project 
Enter the 'common' tab 
See 'encoding' section